# Install copay via npm returns: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm executing an `npm install` as `sudo` to install `copay bitcopay` but for some readon, I get this error.

```
$ sudo npm install
Password:
npm WARN lifecycle copay@2.7.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) copay@2.7.0 bower install /Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/copay
npm WARN lifecycle copay@2.7.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) copay@2.7.0 npm run build /Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/copay
copay@2.7.0 /Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/copay
```

I didn't find a good way to solve it. Someone has an idea to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recently discovered, [this explanation](https://til.codes/npm-install-failed-with-cannot-run-in-wd-2/) hits it on the head.

As Manu says:

> On digging a bit deep, I found that NPM tries to downgrade its
>   privileges when it runs scripts. That downgrading the privileges
>   causes this error.

I was running into a similar problem trying to run in a docker container as root. The "npm install --unsafe-perm" solution worked for me.

jfroma from hacker news says "don't do this". While they explain the situation, they don't provide an explanation for why it's unsafe and refers you to the [npm config page](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) , however, that page only explains that it's a true/false configuration around whether priviledges are de-escalated during the install.

Actually, if you look at [the broader conversation that jfroma's comment is in](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8947493) you could infer the danger is that an npm package could easily have "rm -fr /" in it. If you run npm as root with --unsafe-perm to install that package, you're going to be sad.

Since I'm running this install in a docker container for a build that I'm re-creating every time from source, it's probably safe enough. I can always go back to the repo to get my stuff back.

If you're trying to install something on your workstation, perhaps [adjusting the permissions of your installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) would work better?